# Type check in all array elements

Tags: php, arrays, types

Is there any simple way of checking if all elements of an array are instances of a specific type without looping all elements? Or at least an easy way to get all elements of type X from an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot achieve this without checking all the array elements, but you can use built-in array functions to help you.

You can use [**`array_filter`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to *return* an array. You need to supply your own *callback* function as the second argument to check for a specific type. This will check if the numbers of the array are *even*.

```
function even($var){
  return(!($var & 1));
}

// assuming $yourArr is an array containing integers.
$newArray = array_filter($yourArr, "even");
// will return an array with only even integers.
```

As per VolkerK's comment, as of PHP 5.3+ you can also pass in an anonymous function as your second argument. This is the equivalent as to the example above.

```
$newArray = array_filter($yourArr, function($x) { return 0===$x%2; } );
```

Comment: With php 5.3+ you can also use anonymous functions `$newArray = array_filter($yourArr, function($x) { return 0===$x%2; } );`

Comment: The second example is misleading.  It implies the implementation from the `even` function in the first example cannot be used in an anonymous function. A **_true_** equivalent using an anonymous function is: `$newArray = array_filter($yourArr, function($x) {return (!($x & 1));});`

Answer (score 6):

```
$s = array("abd","10","10.1");
$s = array_map( gettype , $s);
$t = array_unique($s) ;
if ( count($t) == 1 && $t[0]=="string" ){
    print "ok\n";
}
```

Comment: I actually used the filter solution since my requirements changed by this answer is great! That actually completely answer the initial question and is really useful for validation.
Thanks.

Comment: I believe gettype needs to be put inside parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any simple way of checking if all elements of an array [something something something] without looping all elements?

No. You can't check all the elements of an array without checking all the elements of the array.

Though you can use `array_walk` to save yourself writing the boilerplate yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can also combine `array_walk` with `create_function` and use an anonymous function to filter the array. Something alon the lines of:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, create_function('$e', 'return is_int($e)'))
```

Comment: Need to use single quotes, or escape the $ with a backslash.

Comment: In this particular case, there's no need to create a function: `array_filter($array, 'is_int')`. Since `is_int` returns a boolean, that's all you should need...