# Is it possible to define the type of array needed in args?

Tags: php, function, class

i would like to do something like this:

```
class CCC {}  
function abc(array of CCC $variable)
```

Is this possible in php?

Comment: Partial match: [Type check in all array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323013/type-check-in-all-array-elements)

Comment: ... and the long answer depends on why do you need this. If it'd be sufficient to check arguments in runtime, deceze's answer is right for you. But if what you need is IDE assistance, I suggest checking [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects) for plenty of helpful hints. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

You'll need to manually check:

```
function foo(array $arr) {
    if (array_filter($arr, function ($i) { return !($i instanceof CCC); })) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Array must contain instances of CCC');
    }

    ...
}
```